Probability of 2 consecutive heads in an odd number of flips

Bob throws a fair coin repeatedly until he gets 2 heads in a row. What is the probability this happens in an odd number of flips?

Since we are only concerned about obtaining 2 heads in the row, we don't really care about the previous flips:
P(2 heads in a row on an odd number of flips) = $\frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} + \frac{1}{2^7} + ... = \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{6}$
Is this correct?

Surprised by the down vote and the vote to close.  The original poster clearly made a good faith effort to solve the problem, and showed their work.

Just to say, the core logic is right here, in that you can compute it as $\sum p_{2n+1}$ where $p_n$ is the probability that it takes exactly $n$ steps to win.  $p_n$ is a bit messy though.  You can get it recursively, using the recursion $p_n=\frac 12p_{n-1}+\frac 14 p_{n-2}$.  that can be solved in closed form and then you just have to sum some geometric series, but this is much harder than recursive methods.

In fact $p_n$ here is just $\frac{F_{n-1}}{2^n}$.  The fact that probabilities sum to $1$ gives the following nice identity for free: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{F_{n-1}}{2^n} =1.$$ Both this identity, and the identity $$\sum_{n ,{\rm odd}, n>1} \frac{F_{n-1}}{2^n} =\frac25,$$ can be derived using the identity $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, which is somewhat less messy than using geometric series.  The two answers below effectively do this recursion, without taking the detour to Fibonacci numbers, but it is nice to see them behind the scenes.

Addendum added to respond to the comment/question of Jagerber48.

No, it isn't correct.  For example, consider the term $~\dfrac{1}{2^5},~$ which supposedly represents the probability that the first occurrence of two heads in a row occurs on the $~5$-th flip.
You can reason that flips $~3, ~4, ~$ and $~5~$ must be THH, but you can not assume that (for example) flips $~1~$ and $~2~$ must be TT.  In fact, the first two flips can be anything except HH.  So, the specific term should be $~\dfrac{3}{2^5}.$

Let $~A~$ denote the event that the first occurrence of two consecutive heads occurs after an even number of coin flips.
Let $~B~$ denote the event that the first occurrence of two consecutive heads occurs after an odd number of coin flips.
Consider the various possibilities after the first coin flip.
If it is a heads, then:

If the next coin flip is a heads, then event $~A~$ has occurred.

If the next coin flip is a tails, then you are back where you started.


If it is a tails, then:

It is as if event $~A~$ and event $~B~$ have switched places.

Putting this all together, you have that
$$p(A) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{p(A)}{4} + \frac{1 - p(A)}{2} \implies $$
$$\frac{5p(A)}{4} = \frac{3}{4} \implies p(A) = \frac{3}{5} \implies p(B) = \frac{2}{5}.$$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Responding to the comment/question of Jagerber48:

Could you please spell out in more detail how you go from your bulleted texts to your equation for the probability?

Note that $~p(A) + p(B) = 1,~$ since exactly one of the two mutually exclusive events, $~A~$ or $~B,~$ must occur.
When computing $~p(A)~$ you are faced with three mutually exclusive events, which cover all possibilities, as described below.

$\underline{\text{The first two coin flips are Heads, Heads:}}$
The probability of this happening is $~\dfrac{1}{4}.~$
When this does happen, then event $~A~$ has just occurred.
Therefore, the probability of event $~A~$ happening, when the first two coin flips are Heads, Heads is $~1~$ (i.e. certainty).
So, the combined probability of the first two coin flips being Heads, Heads and event $~A~$ also occurring is
$$\frac{1}{4} \times 1.$$

$\underline{\text{The first two coin flips are Heads, Tails:}}$
The probability of this happening is $~\dfrac{1}{4}.~$
Now, if this does happen, how has this affected whether event $~A~$ will occur?
Event $~A~$ represents that the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads occurs on one of the coin flips $~2, ~4, ~6, ~8, \cdots .$
Since there was no occurrence of two consecutive Heads on coin flip $~2,~$ in order for the event $~A~$ to still occur, you must have that the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads must occur on one of the coin flips $~4, ~6, ~8, \cdots .$
At this point, since exactly two coin flips have already occurred, this is equivalent to the event that, from this point forward, the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads occurs on one of the coin flips $~2, ~4, ~6, ~8, \cdots .$ 
That is, since the first two coin flips have been Heads, Tails, the (original) event $~A~$ will occur if and only if, from this point forward, event $~A~$ occurs.
So, the combined probability of the first two coin flips being Heads, Tails and the original event $~A~$ also occurring is
$$\frac{1}{4} \times p(A).$$

$\underline{\text{The first coin flip is Tails:}}$
The probability of this happening is $~\dfrac{1}{2}.~$
Now, if this does happen, how has this affected whether event $~A~$ will occur?
Event $~A~$ represents that the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads occurs on one of the coin flips $~2, ~4, ~6, ~8, \cdots .$
Since the first coin flip was Tails, there can be no occurrence of two consecutive Heads on coin flip $~2.~$
So, in order for the event $~A~$ to still occur, you must have that the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads must occur on one of the coin flips $~4, ~6, ~8, \cdots .$
At this point, since exactly one coin flip has already occurred, this is equivalent to the event that, from this point forward, the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads occurs on one of the coin flips $~3, ~5, ~7, ~9, \cdots .$ 
Further, the specification for event $~B~$ is that the first occurrence of two consecutive Heads occurs on one of the coin flips $~3, ~5, ~7, ~9, \cdots .$ 
So, since the first coin flip has been Tails, the (original) event $~A~$ will occur if and only if, from this point forward, event $~B~$ occurs.
So, the combined probability of the first coin flip being Tails and the original event $~A~$ also occurring is
$$\frac{1}{4} \times p(B) = \frac{1}{4} \times [ ~1 - p(A) ~].$$

So, you have three mutually exclusive events, [Heads, Heads], [Heads, Tails] and [Tails], which cover all possibilities.
Construing these events as Event-1, Event-2, Event-3, you have that
$$p(A)$$
$$ = \left[ ~p( ~\text{Event-1} ~) \times p( ~A, ~\text{given that Event-1 occurred} ~) ~\right]$$
$$ + \left[ ~p( ~\text{Event-2} ~) \times p( ~A, ~\text{given that Event-2 occurred} ~) ~\right]$$
$$ + \left[ ~p( ~\text{Event-3} ~) \times p( ~A, ~\text{given that Event-3 occurred} ~) ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{p(A)}{4} + \frac{1 - p(A)}{2}.$$

Are you sure about this ? THH could occur at odd # of throws at $3,5,7, .....$ and at even # of throws at $2,4,6,8,....$ Somehow it is reminding me of the hotel with an infinite number of rooms

@trueblueanil Both of the corresponding infinite series must be convergent, because $~0 < p(A),p(B) < 1 ~: ~p(A) + p(B) = 1.~$  Beyond that, I double checked for an analytical mistake, and couldn't find one.  Given my lack of formal training in probability theory, it is certainly possible that there is a subtle flaw in my analysis that I simply can't detect.  Or it is possible that my analysis is right.

@trueblueanil The only really tricky part is that if the first throw is a tails, then events $~A~$ and $~B~$ have switched places.

This works fine. $\quad$ As an alternative, you can calculate the probability conditional on the first toss. $P(A|H) = 1/4 + 1/4P(A|H) + 1/4P(A|T), P(A|T) = 1/4P(A|H) + 1/2P(A|T)$. Solve this system to get $P(A|H) + P(A|T) = 3/5$.

@user2661923 This is brilliant! Reminds me of this question.

I did a quick numerical experiment with a million coin toss and found out these results in 3 different program runs:
EVEN: 599869 -- ODD: 400131
EVEN: 599952 -- ODD: 400048
EVEN: 600387 -- ODD: 399613
That is consistent with the 60%-40% result

@pygri What did you use as the upper bound on the number of coin tosses?  For example, on any given run, it is theoretically possible that you could have $~1000~$ coin flips, with no occurrence of $~2~$ consecutive heads.  How did you program this?  Did you simply assume no upper bound, and instead rely on the fact that realistically, sooner or later the run would end?  Alternatively, how did you program your software to score  the situation where there was no occurrence of two consecutive heads?

@user2661923 that is a good point and yes in principle the number of coin tosses could grow unbounded until you get an HH result, however in practice I set an upper limit of 100 - in the case where there would be no matches with less than 100 coins toss my program would crash and I would have to restart it with a higher number of max tosses. But I did not need to do that, that means that the limit of 100 was enough in my relatively small sample. As an example, in a run of the program I just did, I got 69 as the highest place where a HH was found out of the million runs.

Could you please spell out in more detail how you go from your bulleted texts to your equation for the probability?

@Jagerber48 See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.


Since we are only concerned about obtaining 2 heads in the row, we don't really care about the previous flips

You don't care about the exact sequence of previous flips, but you do care about the parity of the number of flips so far, and about the prior flip.
You also must assume that two heads in a row have not occurred earlier in the sequence, but it is not correct to suppose that all of the prior flips were tails, which is where your proposed solution falls down.
We can approach the problem by grouping all states of ongoing trials into four categories, which I will represent with symbols of the form $p_n$, where $p = e,o$ represents the parity of the number of flips so far, and $n = 0,1$ is the length of the run of heads preceding the current flip.
The initial state of each trial is in category $e_0$: an even number (0) of previous flips, and 0 consecutive heads immediately preceding that point.  In such a state, the next flip has probability $1\over2$ to transition to each of states $o_0$ (if tails) and $o_1$ (if heads). Therefore, the probability of the experiment ending after an odd number of flips is $$Pr(odd) = Pr(odd|e_0) = {1 \over 2}Pr(odd|o_0) + {1 \over 2}Pr(odd|o_1)$$
In any $o_1$ state, there is probability $1\over2$ of flipping tails, thereby returning to an $e_0$ state, and probability $1\over2$ of flipping heads, ending the trial after an even number of flips. Thus, $$Pr(odd|o_1) = {1\over2}Pr(odd|e_0) + {1\over2}(0)$$
Similarly, $$Pr(odd|o_0) = {1\over2}Pr(odd|e_0) + {1\over2}Pr(odd|e_1)$$
and  $$Pr(odd|e_1) = {1\over2}Pr(odd|o_0) + {1\over2}(1)$$
Taking the four conditional probabilities as unknowns, there are four equations in four unknowns, which can be solved algebraically.
I trust that the algebra is well within your capabilities, so I skip the not-so-gory details and go straight to the punchline: $Pr(odd) = Pr(odd|e_0) = {2\over5}$.
This is in some sense a dual of the solution presented by @user2661923, being a little less direct to the desired probability but a little more clearly associated with the details of the trial.

I model it as two players, Alice and Bob tossing alternately with A throwing first, so she can win only on odd number of tosses thrown. Then, with the suffixes showing # of heads held at time of toss, and boundary conditions set so that only A can win,
we frame equations toss by toss to get
$A_0 = \frac12B_1 + \frac12 B_0 \tag 1$
$B_0 = \frac12 A_0 + \frac12A_1 \tag2$
$A_1 = \frac12\times 1 + \frac12B_0 \tag3$
$B_1= \frac12\times 0 + \frac12A_0 \tag4$
Solving the system of linear equations, we get
P(two successive heads first occurs after an odd # of tosses)
= P(A wins from start)
=   $A_0 = \frac25$
